# XML to Linq getting child nodes with attribute value

Tags: c#, xml, linq, datatable

Variations of this question have already been asked but I have not found one that can help me with the problem i am having.

Given and XML file of this format:

```
<TopLevel>
    <SecondLevel Name="Name" Color="Blue">
         <ChildNode1></ChildNode1>
         <ChildNode2></ChildNode2>
    </SecondLevel>
    <SecondLevel Name="Name2" Color="Red">
         ...
    </SecondLevel>
</topLevel>
```

I have the value to the attribute Color.
What I would like is to be able to first find the `Name` corresponding to that color, and then find all the childnodes.

I prefer to use Xelement over XDocument.

This is what I have attempted so far, but with no luck.

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load("XmlFile.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> Name2=
           from el in xelement.Elements("SecondLevel")
           where el.Attribute("Color") == "Red"
           select el;
```

With the result of that, I will eventually want to format it into a datatable. Is this doable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just missing cast of attribute to string (or getting it's value directly - see notes at the end). Also you can select `Name` attribute value to have sequence of strings instead of XElements:

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load("XmlFile.xml");
IEnumerable<string> names =
           from el in xelement.Elements("SecondLevel")
           where (string)el.Attribute("Color") == "Red" // here
           select (string)el.Attribute("Name");
```

NOTE: You can also access attribute value directly with `el.Attribute("Color").Value` but that will throw exception if element don't have `Color` attribute. So casting is more safe, but accessing value can be option if you want your code to fail fast if xml is not valid.

BTW you can also use XPath to get second level elements which have required color:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> secondLevels = 
      xelement.XPathSelectElements("SecondLevel[@Color='Red']");
```

Comment: This is great because it finds the Name attribute associated with the color, but what If I wanted child nodes of the `SecondLevel`node?

Comment: @moalaz then just leave your code as is - `select el` without projection to Name attribute value. Thus you will have sequence of XElements

Comment: Perfect! Does anyone know of an easy way to put the childnodes in a dataTable?

Comment: @moalaz you can select their values and create DataTable with [custom CopyToDataTable method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx)

Comment: XPathSelectElements is in an extension method in a different namespace.  System.Xml.XPath